# Problema con Web Service ASMX al consumirlo desde Android

Tags: asp.net, .asmx

Tengo un problema con el servicio web en `asmx` que guarda imágenes y que consumo desde una app de Android:

Esta es el error que genera:

> System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como
>   instancia de un objeto. en
>   WebServicesLogistica.ServicesLogistica.CreateRequest() en
>   c:\Users\SOPORTE\Desktop\PROYECTO
>   LOGISTICO\WebSistemaLogisticoR\WebServicesLogistica\WebServi‌​cesLogistica\Service‌​sLogistica.asmx.cs:l‌​ínea
>   303

Código del servicio:

```
  [WebMethod]    
    public void SaveImage()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Upload")))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Upload/"));
            }

            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Upload/").ToString();
            var Request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];
                file.SaveAs(path + file.FileName);
            }  
        }

    catch(Exception ex){
        throw ex;
    }
  }
```

Mando en `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Nos podrías dar más detalle al respecto, ¿Cuál es el error que te manda exactamente? ¿En qué línea?

Comment: me sale error 500 cuando mando de mi aplicacion android una imagen

Comment: ¿Si intentas consumir tu servicio desde un navegador sí lo puedes ver sin ningún problema?

Comment: si hice la prueba con postman y si carga la imagen

Comment: ¿Tu servicio se encuentra publicado en alguna red local o en internet?

Comment: localmente en mi red

Comment: ¿Nos podrías compartir todo el mensaje del error que te manda cuando intentas consumir el servicio?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. en WebServicesLogistica.ServicesLogistica.CreateRequest() en c:\Users\SOPORTE\Desktop\PROYECTO LOGISTICO\WebSistemaLogisticoR\WebServicesLogistica\WebServicesLogistica\ServicesLogistica.asmx.cs:línea 303

Comment: Bien, lo que está pasando es que al consumir el servicio existe una variable no inicializada (en el servicio web) y por eso te envía el error `Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto`. Tendrás que realizar`debug` de ese servicio recibiendo los mismos parámetros y ver el comportamiento, seguramente con eso saldrá el error

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 303 del archivo mencionado en el mensaje de error?